# Google Maps InfoWindow not displaying complete text in Firefox

Tags: css, google-maps, firefox

I am using the code available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) in my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/g09hx37r/17/).

The problem is that the text in the info window is appearing like this:

[image: It should say: You are here.]

It should say: You are here. (in a single line)

Using Firebug, I changed the text's parent style to have width 75px but then a horizontal scrollbar appeared on the text in the info window. I tried to hide that scrollbar using Firebug and it worked but when I put it in the code, the scrollbar appears again.

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 62.5%;        /* so, 10px = 1rem */
}

#button-container{
}

button{
    color: white;
    background: #4196c2;
    border: 0rem;
    border-radius: 0rem 0rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#show-hide{
    height: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 0;
}

#map-canvas{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gm-style-iw div{
    /*width: 75px;
    overflow: hidden;*/
}

.gm-style-iw div div{
/*    overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control infoWindow content width by putting html with inline styles in its content like this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map,
    position: pos,
    content: '<div style="width: 75px">You are here.</div>'
});
```

this width is changed dynamically and put into inline styles which have priority over css, thats why it gets overriden even when you put changes in css